# Change attribute values by xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml file:

```
<xc:XmlCache xmlns:xc="XmlCache" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xmlns:fx="mx.MarketParameters.Forex" xmlns:fxsp="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Spot">
 <xc:XmlCacheArea xc:value="MarketParameters">
  <mp:nickName xc:value="MDS" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters">
   <mp:date xc:value="20130315">
    <fx:forex xmlns:fx="mx.MarketParameters.Forex">
     <fxsp:spot xmlns:fxsp="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Spot">
      <fxsp:pair xc:value="AUD/AED" xc:type="Fields">
       <mp:ask xc:keyFormat="N">1.0000000</mp:ask> 
       <mp:bid xc:keyFormat="N">1.0000000</mp:bid> 
       <mp:formFactor xc:keyFormat="N">1</mp:formFactor> 
       <mp:high xc:keyFormat="N">0.0000000</mp:high> 
       <mp:low xc:keyFormat="N">0.0000000</mp:low> 
       <mp:mid xc:keyFormat="N">1.0000000</mp:mid> 
       <mp:quotation xc:keyFormat="C">AUD-AED</mp:quotation> 
      </fxsp:pair>
      <fxsp:pair xc:value="BHD/AED" xc:type="Fields">
       <mp:ask xc:keyFormat="N">0.8264463</mp:ask> 
       <mp:bid xc:keyFormat="N">0.8264463</mp:bid> 
       <mp:formFactor xc:keyFormat="N">1</mp:formFactor> 
       <mp:high xc:keyFormat="N">0.0000000</mp:high> 
       <mp:low xc:keyFormat="N">0.0000000</mp:low> 
       <mp:mid xc:keyFormat="N">0.8264463</mp:mid> 
       <mp:quotation xc:keyFormat="C">BHD-AED</mp:quotation> 
      </fxsp:pair>
     </fxsp:spot>
    </fx:forex>
   </mp:date>
  </mp:nickName>
 </xc:XmlCacheArea>
</xc:XmlCache>
```

I'm looking for a way to do two things:
1. remove all elements but two -> mp:ask and mp:bid
2. change the numeric values of those two elements to other values I have in a csv file.

Expected output

```
<xc:XmlCache xmlns:xc="XmlCache" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xmlns:fx="mx.MarketParameters.Forex" xmlns:fxsp="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Spot">
<xc:XmlCacheArea xc:value="MarketParameters">
<mp:nickName xc:value="MDS" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters">
<mp:date xc:value="20130315">
<fx:forex xmlns:fx="mx.MarketParameters.Forex">
<fxsp:spot xmlns:fxsp="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Spot">
<fxsp:pair xc:value="AUD/AED" xc:type="Fields">
<mp:ask xc:keyFormat="N">1.0000000</mp:ask> 
<mp:bid xc:keyFormat="N">1.0000000</mp:bid> 
</fxsp:pair>
<fxsp:pair xc:value="BHD/AED" xc:type="Fields">
<mp:ask xc:keyFormat="N">0.8264463</mp:ask> 
<mp:bid xc:keyFormat="N">0.8264463</mp:bid> 
</fxsp:pair>
</fxsp:spot>
</fx:forex>
</mp:date>
</mp:nickName>
</xc:XmlCacheArea>
</xc:XmlCache>
```

The idea would be to update the values in the output xml with the ones provided in the csv file (first value is bid, second one is ask). If need be the csv file could be converted to xml, that is no issue.

```
CSV file
AUD/AED;25;25
BHD/AED;20;20
```

The file comes from an application we use. Once the values are changed, the goal is to re-import the file into the application.
I tried lots of things in xsl, but I must say I don't see how I can get it to work.

Can somebode help?

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question to show the output you are expecting here? Also, could you elaborate by what you mean when you say "other values I have in a CSV file". Perhaps you can show this CSV file too, although I fear extracting values from it with XSLT could be tricky (You would almost certainly need to use XSLT 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do convert your CSV file to XML. XSLT obviously works best with XML. Also, you would almost certainly have to use XSLT 2.0 to have any chance of parsing a non-XML file. So, for the purposes of this answer, I am assuming the look up file looks like this

```
<csv>
   <record code="AUD/AED" bid="25" ask="25" />
   <record code="BHD/AED" bid="20" ask="20" />
</csv>
```

In terms of doing the transformation, if you are not already, you should be building upon the XSLT identity transform to copy all existing nodes as a start.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This means you only have to write additional templates for the nodes/attributes you do want to change.

You say you want to remove all (leaf) elements apart from 'bid' and 'ask', well, you can write a template like this, to ignore all others

```
<xsl:template match="fxsp:pair/*[not(self::mp:ask) and not(self::mp:bid)]" />
```

The only other template you need is one that matches the text nodes under any other elements that are not excluded (i.e this will only now match your 'ask' and 'bid' elements)

```
<xsl:template match="fxsp:pair/*/text()">
```

Within this you can do your lookup from the 'lookup' file

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('lookup.xml')//record[@code=$code]/@*[local-name()=$attr]"/>
```

In this case, **$code** is set to the attribute value of **xc:value** from **fxsp:pair**, and **$attr** is the name of the current element ('ask' or 'bid').

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xc="XmlCache" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xmlns:fx="mx.MarketParameters.Forex" xmlns:fxsp="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Spot">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fxsp:pair/*[not(self::mp:ask) and not(self::mp:bid)]" />

  <xsl:template match="fxsp:pair/@xc:type" />

  <xsl:template match="fxsp:pair/*/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="../../@xc:value" />
    <xsl:variable name="attr" select="local-name(..)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="document('lookup.xml')//record[@code=$code]/@*[local-name()=$attr]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, you can put the "document" reference in a variable, which may simplify things (and indeed improve efficiency). Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xc="XmlCache" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xmlns:fx="mx.MarketParameters.Forex" xmlns:fxsp="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Spot">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('lookup.xml')//record" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fxsp:pair/*[not(self::mp:ask) and not(self::mp:bid)]" />

  <xsl:template match="fxsp:pair/@xc:type" />

  <xsl:template match="fxsp:pair/*/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="../../@xc:value" />
    <xsl:variable name="attr" select="local-name(..)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$lookup[@code=$code]/@*[local-name()=$attr]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I would also like to remove the xc:type attribute from the fxsp:pair element. I tried adding <xsl:template match="fxsp:pair/@xc:type" /> but this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Adding that should work, unless you have added other templates that match the same attribute that are taking priority, or maybe there is code that does **xsl:copy-of** for the attributes, rather than **xsl:apply-templates**. In any case, I have amended my examples to include that line, and both examples work as expected.

Comment: One last question. Would there be a way to not change the values when the code is not available in the lookup file? Now every time one is missing, I don't get any value at all.

Comment: What you could do is store the results of the lookup in a variable, and then use an **xsl:choose** to determine whether to change the value or copy the existing one.